# Move text in input field to the left

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to know how to move the text to the left when I attach something to it.
This is the current state of the art:

[image: textfocus]

As you can see, the text stays on the first inserted chars (of course, this does not happen when the text is entered manually).

Code:

```html
<input type="text" class="calc-previous-display" value="0" disabled />
<input type="text" class="calc-display" value="0" disabled />
```

```css
.calc-display,
.calc-previous-display {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background-color: var(--color-alt);
  color: var(--color-0);
  text-align: right;
  padding: var(--display-space);
}

.calc-display {
  font-size: var(--display-1-text);
}

.calc-previous-display {
  font-size: var(--display-0-text);
  border-bottom: var(--display-split);
}
```

```js
function insertValue(el, val) {
  el.value += val;
}
```

I tried .focus, but I didn't get what I expected..

**The goal is to prevent this:**
[image]

**CLARIFICATION ABOUT THE GOAL:**

1. Prevent text to get back (at the start) when the input is disabled.
2. Even is input is disabled, if something get append the text should follow.

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure to understand the request.. do you want the text in the input field to align to the left when you are typing text inside? and go back to the right when you are done? but on the other hand you said _"this does not happen when the text is entered manually"_ ... so I really don't get what exactly you are asking for

Comment: I want the text to be right aligned at the beginning and when something is appended, the focus stays on the right.

Comment: ok by focus.. you actually mean the caret? that blinking vertical lign? isn't it?

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking.  Can you please expand your code sample in a way that demonstrates the problem you're having?  [mcve]

Comment: You can understand it from the example posted by @DiegoD

Comment: I spent the past 2 hours on it and frankly I'm still clueless.. so if my example is enough to understand the issue I'm afraid I'm the first one that didn't get it yet

Comment: @DiegoD I edit the post with the goal that need to be achieved

Comment: I saw your edit and trust me it didn't add any meaningful information because my solution already behave exactly like that. Please can I ask you what browser are you using? and which version? if you are using a mobile phone or a desktop also

Comment: Gif added. I'm currently on the last version of Safari from Desktop (tested on Chrome too).

Comment: ok finally I see what you are seeing... and yes that's not the intended behaviour. I was using firefox 107 here and I was having the correct behaviour. I tested now with chrome 108 and now I can see there the same bad result you have on safari. I apologize I didn't get the point. I had no idea. When disabled, the focus action doesn't behave as expected there. I'll try to see if I can find a better solution.. of course anyone else feel free to make the same attempt

Comment: After all this conversation it was impossible not to understand each other, forgive me if I thought late about the gif.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I used a very simple `<div>` having the  `contenteditable="true"` attribute so that it will be in the condition to receive input from user like if it was a regular textbox.

The key was using the `scrollLeft` property of the element (styled as `overflow: hidden;`) to move the scrolling bar all the way to the right each time a new digit gets appended.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft

The input text will remain on a single line because of the style `white-space: nowrap;`.

Everything else is just bells and whistles.

Tested and working both on Firefox and Chrome (latest versions). Hopefully working also with Safari.

```js
//on document ready inits UI
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
    const target = document.getElementById('disable');
    const state = target.dataset.state;
    target.innerHTML = states[state].label;    
    input.contentEditable = states[state].contenteditable;
});

//max number length allowed (to fit inside the #monitor with no overflow)
const maxLength = 13;

//available states for content editable
const states = [
  {
    state: 0,
    label: 'CONTENT EDITABLE DISABLED',
    contenteditable: false
  },
  {
    state: 1,
    label: 'CONTENT EDITABLE ENABLED <br>(navigation only)',
    contenteditable: true
  },
  {
    state: 2,
    label: 'CONTENT EDITABLE ENABLED',
    contenteditable: true
  }
];

//click handler for #gotoEnd button
document.querySelector('#gotoEnd')
  .addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    scrollToEnd();
  });
  
//click handler for #disable button
document.querySelector('#disable')
  .addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  
    const target = event.target;
    const input = document.getElementById('input');
    
    const currentState = parseInt(target.dataset.state);
    let nextState = -1;
    
    if(currentState == 2)
      nextState = 0;
    else
      nextState = currentState + 1;      
    
    target.dataset.state = nextState;
    target.innerHTML = states[nextState].label;    
    input.contentEditable = states[nextState].contenteditable;
  });


//click handler for .digit buttons
document.querySelectorAll('.keypad > .digit').forEach(digitKey => {
  digitKey.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const clickedDigit = event.target;
    const digit = clickedDigit.dataset.digit;
    appendDigit(digit);
  });
});

//click handler for .ce button
document.querySelector('.keypad > .key.ce')
  .addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    input.textContent = '0';
    mirrorMonitor();
  });

//click handler for .backspace button
document.querySelector('.keypad > .key.backspace')
  .addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    input.textContent = input.textContent.slice(0, -1);
    if (input.textContent === '')
      input.textContent = '0';
    mirrorMonitor();
  });

//keypress handler for #input (preventing input different from numbers)
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {    
  const state = document.getElementById('disable').dataset.state;                 
  //if state == 1 it means only navigation is allowed
  if (state == '1')
    event.preventDefault();
  //otherwise allows only numbers
  if (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  //if the input exceeded the maxLength, prevents adding text
  if( event.target.textContent.length === maxLength)
    event.preventDefault();
});

//keyup handler for #input (so that it will mirror on #monitor)
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {    
  mirrorMonitor();
});

//appends a digit to the #input (mirroring the #monitor)
function appendDigit(digit) {
  const input = document.getElementById('input');

if (input.textContent === '0')
    input.textContent = '';  
    
  if(input.textContent.length === maxLength)
    return;
    
  input.textContent += digit;

  scrollToEnd();  
  mirrorMonitor();
}

//mirrors the value of the #input on #monitor
function mirrorMonitor(){  
  const monitor = document.getElementById('monitor');
  const input = document.getElementById('input');
  monitor.textContent = input.textContent;
  
}

//scroll the cursor to the rightmost position in #input
function scrollToEnd() {
  const input = document.getElementById('input');
  const index = input.innerText.length;
  const maxScrollLeft = input.scrollWidth - input.clientWidth;
  input.scrollLeft = maxScrollLeft;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: dashed 4px lightgray;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 1rem;  
}

.info h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;  
}

.info ul {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.info ul li {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.calculator {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 250px;
}

#monitor{
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;  
  text-align: right;
  padding: .2rem;
  background: #364f52;
  color: #c9d2c5;  
  margin-bottom: .2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#input {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8rem;
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  background: #364f52;
  color: #c9d2c5;
  border: solid 8px #323e45;
  margin-bottom: .2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.navigation{
  display: flex;
  gap: .2rem;
}

#disable{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: .2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: solid 2px #323e45;
}

#disable.active{  
  background: gray;
}

#gotoEnd{
  width: 3rem;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1rem;  
  margin-bottom: .2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: solid 2px #323e45;
}

.keypad {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*border: solid 2px #323e45;*/
}

.keypad > .key {
  flex: 0 0 33.3%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid 2px #323e45;
}

.keypad > .ce {
  background: #e08151;
}

.keypad > .backspace {
  background: #85a98c;
}

.keypad > .digit {
  color: #364f52;
  background: #c9d2c5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="calculator">
    <div id="monitor" class="max">0</div>    
    <div id="input" contenteditable="true">0</div>    
    <div class="navigation">
      <button id="disable" data-state="0" title="click to toggle among 3 states">asdf</button>
      <button id="gotoEnd" title="move to rightmost position">&gt;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="keypad">
      <button class="key ce">C</button>
      <button class="key backspace" data-digit="2">&lt;</button>
      <button class="key digit digit-0" data-digit="0">0</button>
      <button class="key digit digit-1" data-digit="1">1</button>
      <button class="key digit digit-2" data-digit="2">2</button>
      <button class="key digit digit-3" data-digit="3">3</button>
      <button class="key digit digit-4" data-digit="4">4</button>
      <button class="key digit digit-5" data-digit="5">5</button>
      <button class="key digit digit-6" data-digit="6">6</button>
      <button class="key digit digit-7" data-digit="7">7</button>
      <button class="key digit digit-8" data-digit="8">8</button>
      <button class="key digit digit-9" data-digit="9">9</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="info">    
    <div>
      <h1>Calculator Demo</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>When you press a digit button, it will be appended to the input</li>
        <li>The text will automatically scroll to the rightmost position</li>
        <li>But yet the input is of type content editable and gives freedom to edit text anywhere still preventing to insert text not being numbers (as long such state was enabled)</li>
        <li>When given focus, navigate with the arrow keys</li>
        <li>Even if the input has focus, wherever is the cursor, if a digit is pressed on the keypad, the number will be appended at the end of the input string</li>
        <li>You can toggle the content editable property of the input using the dedicated button and it will behave like the control is having or not the disabled attribute</li>
        <li>Such button will rotate among 3 possible states: contentEditable = false; contentEditable = true but only arrow keys for navigation are allowed; contentEditable = true but only numbers (and navigation) are allowed;</li>
        <li>In case you moved the cursor anywhere in the input text after enabling the content editable, you can press the <b>&gt;</b> to move to the rightmost position</li>
        <li>The maximum number of digits allowed (13) is ruled by the const maxLength so that the number will fit the #monitor and won't overflow</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, of course it works. But as you can see from the code, the input is 'disabled'. This solution doesn't work in this case.

Comment: It's not perfectly clear how the `disabled` attribute is handled as a whole, but to show how to deal with it inside the append logic, now the function makes sure to set `disabled = false` before performing its action

Comment: At this point, I suspect there is no way to see the last part when input is disabled. (what I need)

Comment: it was hard to understand the conditions you expected that input text to behave. I changed my answer adding the logic that will enable the text input just so that the `focus()` will move the caret to the end and will disable it again before returning. I also added a button that will toggle the disabled state of the input to give the chance to edit its value manually

Comment: Ok, as you can see from your current update, when you append (and `disabled` is false) you see the last insert numbers [fine]. But when you toggle `disabled` to true, it shows the first number again [bad]. The point is that I want the text to be preserved on the last insert. I don't really know how to explain better.

Comment: I updated my answer but I can hardly go anywhere better than that. The text value is always preserved and never overwritten (if you don't toggle the disabled state to enabled and don't edit the value manually). But the whole logic of disabled was totally invented and you were not clear about it. The code itself you shared is just a couple of input texts, an incomplete styling with custom properties not set and total lack of javascript

Comment: The code shared is enough to understand the problem, the point is that you don't get the point. Let me see if I can explain it better in some way.

Comment: _"But when you toggle disabled to true, it shows the first number again [bad]."_ this scenario alone is untrue.. please read it again and prove yourself you are actually doing what it's written there

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Static Template</title>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .calc-display,
    .calc-previous-display {
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      background-color: var(--color-alt);
      color: var(--color-0);
      text-align: right;
      padding: var(--display-space);
    }
    
    .calc-display {
      border: 1px solid red;
      font-size: var(--display-1-text);
      padding: 0.25rem;
    }
    
    .calc-previous-display {
      font-size: var(--display-0-text);
      border-bottom: var(--display-split);
    }
    
    .box {
      background-color: gray;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function append() {
      let v = document.querySelector("#el");
      v.value += 10;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <input type="text" class="calc-display" id="el" />
  </div>
  <button onclick="append()">Append</button>
</body>

</html>
```

the main issue is -- add some padding to your input and set box-sizing to border-box.

Comment: As you can see, you have the same problem here...
You are still looking at the first use 10 and not the last..

Comment: can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: can you give an example of what you want? as we can see what it  is now.

Comment: If you run your snip, you'll see that when you type the text manually, you still see the last character you inserted [correct]. When you use append, you see the string from the beginning and what you insert (at the end) is hidden [wrong].

Comment: " When you use append, you see the string from the beginning and what you insert (at the end) is hidden". I am not seeing that in the above example.  Append and manual entry are behaving exactly the same for me.